# I need list of files in long format that contain string

Tags: unix, count, grep

I want to have the list of files, in long format (`ls -l`) including date and time, that contain an specific string and if possible, number of occurrences.

The most I have achieved is a list of files (just the name) with number of occurrences:

```
grep -c 'string' * | grep -v :0
```

That shows something like:
`filename`:`number of occurrences`

But I cannot improve it to show also file date and time. It has to be something simple, but I am a bit newbie.

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `-s` for ignoring the folder warnings. `':0$'` is the regex for `ending in :0`. `awk` then calls `ls -l` on just the filenames found, then `| tr '\n' ' '` replaces the newlines of the `ls` command with spaces. We output the number of occurences at the end of each line so we don't lose the info while going forward. The last `awk` is to just to print the columns needed.

```
grep -c 'form-group' * -s | grep -v ':0$' | awk -F ':' '{ printf system( "ls -l \"" $2 "\" | tr \"\n\" \" \"" ); print " " $3 }' | awk -F ' ' '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " : " $11 }'
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Sep 1 13:47 xxx.blade.php : 12
Sep 1 13:47 xxx.blade.php : 5
Sep 1 13:47 xxx.blade.php : 6
Sep 11 17:25 xxx.blade.php : 4
Sep 4 15:03 xxx.blade.php : 6
```

Comment: Thousand thanks, Valdrinit! I just had to change $2 into $1 and $3 into $2 in first awk and it works like a charm! Great!

Comment: I am very glad I could have helped you!